# PDF file starts downloading

Tags: pdf

I am giving a link to a pdf file but it starts downloading the file instead of opening it

```
<a href="media/complains.pdf">Complains</a>
```

Comment: So, what is your expected behaviour??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that you don't have a pdf reader plugin installed on your browser.